# IP Address - Convert Internal Address to External Address

Tags: networking, ip-address

I am new to networking and I am wondering if it is possible that there is a way you can convert an internal IP address and convert that to an external IP address. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming home neyworks and NAT: Nope.

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer: No, but that's the wrong question :).

There is absolutely no connection between the internal and external IPs. The internal IP is set by your router (or whatever you have set up as a DHCP server on your LAN unless you are using fixed IPs) and is only valid in your Local Area Network. In a normal home setup, all computers on your LAN have the same external IP even though each has a different internal IP.

It is, however, entirely possible to get your external IP, you just don't get it by somehow processing your internal one. There are many free web services that show your IP. Have a look at

- http://www.whatismyip.com/
- http://cfajohnson.com/ipaddr.cgi
- http://whatismyipaddress.com/

and many, many others.